# copyFromLocal File not found - command to copy infile csv to hdfs location using pyspark script

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm using the following code with in the Spark script. Here, I want to copy the data files from  local to HDFS location. When running the HDFS command from the shell manually it's working fine. But through the py-spark script it's failing.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-copyFromLocal", "-f", local_file,table_hdfs_location], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
return_code = process.wait()

if return_code == 0:
    print("File copy successful")
else:
    print(f"File copy failed. Return code: {return_code}")
    error_output = process.stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
    if error_output:
        print("Error message:")
        print(error_output)
```

Error message:
copyFromLocal: `/data/Infiles/Sales.csv': No such file or directory

This is the local directory(on Linux). Path is exist and file is also present.

Is it becuase the spark unable to find the location across from all the nodes ? How can this local folder needs to be present in all hadoop nodes if I'm are running this hdfs command from spark script.

Comment: perhaps check the ownership & permissions on the file (`ls -l /data/path/to/file.csv`), and verify upper/lowercase (having Uppercase `Infiles` and `Sales.csv` will, imho, cause no end to future confusion, better to just use lowercase unless there's a reason not to). Also check permission/ownership of each directory above the csv file (`/data`, etc) and make sure they're readable by the process running the hdfs command.

Comment: You should run this code snippet outside of Spark. The `hdfs dfs` command can only work on the host where `/data/Infiles/Sales.csv` is reachable, so that's probably the driver node or another machine. Don't try to execute this command on Spark's executor nodes.

Comment: Is there any way to run the **hdfs dfs** command using the py-spark script (spark submit command), where I've 7 nodes. how can the local path accessible to all the working nodes ?

Comment: You can't. As mentioned, this is not Spark code, so don't run it in Spark. Just run `python script.py` where that file exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `--files` to `spark-submit`, which automatically uploads the file to HDFS for you (well, within the YARN executor directory), but then you'd needlessly be duplicating the file, and every executor would try to copy the same file to the same HDFS location.

The general solution to your question is to not use Spark to run the shown code. Just use `python`, or otherwise a shell script that wraps `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` and `spark-submit`

Comment: Thanks for your response @onecricketeer. I tried with the **--files** in the **spark-submit** command. But I'm getting the below 

[2023-12-11, 06:32:55 UTC] {ssh.py:171} INFO - Local_File: /data/pmm_di/Infiles/*
[2023-12-11, 06:32:57 UTC] {ssh.py:175} WARNING - Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/data/pmm_di/Infiles/ForecastandRTF.csv

It's giving some jar file issues. I'm passing the directory which needs to distribute across the worker nodes in the Spark cluster.

Comment: 1) Sounds like you did supply the arguments correctly to spark-submit. The files argument or csv file does not go at the very end 2) The second part of my first paragraph says not to use that approach...

Comment: Thanks . I'll go ahead with python script.